# Does it matter who adds coins to the Despair coffer?

Tags: tokens, dont-rest-your-head

I suspect I'm fretting over a trivial loose end in the rules, but I *might* be missing something pretty fundamental about the coin economy, so I'd like to get it cleared up.

On page 24, the book says that when pain dominates it "has a game effect of requiring the player to place a coin of despair into the GM’s despair coffer." Similarly page 34 says, "If pain dominates, you pay a greater price. Pay a coin into the GM’s despair coffer."

I'm clear that each participant in the game is expected to show up with "a handful of pocket change" (page 3). It seems reasonable to assume these are the coins which go into the GM's despair coffer, and they seem to have no mechanical value before that.

However! The example on page 5 has the GM paying a coin into the Despair coffer herself ("Lydia [the GM] places a coin into a dark bowl sitting on the table and continues"), while the example on page 24 has the player doing so ("Ash [a player] places a coin of despair into the GM’s coffer").

On the one hand, it seems irrelevant who puts the coin into the coffer, and why else would the GM be asked to bring change? On the other hand... the entire rest of the book specifically tasks the player to contribute the coin, and often uses words like "pay" and "price" to describe the action. Maybe I'm reading too much into that, but it seems deliberate and consistent.

**Does it matter who pays into the Despair coffer?** If so, why?

Answer (score 4):

There is no *mechanical* difference to who pays the coin. But! It may help the player who "screwed up" feel like they're directly responsible for the growing, well, despair. Just a bit of theatrics to set the mood.